# Filter a Flux with a HashSet cellected from another Flux

Tags: spring-boot, filtering, spring-webflux, hashset

I have two flux coming from ReactiveMongoDB API:
the first will gets the data of **date1**
the second one gets the data of **date2**
by the end i want to exclude elements that still appearing from the date1 in date2, In order to get those that are disappeared and save them in another collection.
To deal with That I used a HashSet to collect the element of the second date (date2), so I can filter the flux of the first date (date2) by excluding the element in the hashset.

```java
Flux<Report> reportOfCurrentDate = reportRepository.get(LocalDate.now());
Flux<Report> reportOfPrevDate = reportRepository.get(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1));

reportOfCurrentDate.log("insert In Set :").collect(Collectors.toSet());

// filtering 
reportOfPrevDate
.filterWhen(
                report -> resourceIds
                        .map(installedResId -> !installedResId.contains(report.getInstalledResInstalledResourceId()))
)
.transform(rereports -> resolvedRepository.insertAll(reports.collectList())
.blockLast();
```

**Note  that the flux is getting the data form a very large collection**
The problem is i get just one flux running (the one that insert in a set) it doesn't seem reactive the behavior expected is that the two fluxs will run in parallel, filtering data, and insert in the end in a new collection.
any one can help me with that, or suggest another way of doing it ?

Comment: Hey! Did you resolve your problem? I’m also wondering to know how to handle cases like you described.

Comment: yes, I've resolved it; what I did is block the insertion in the set to have all elements I want to filter with, then using onComplete I trigger the filtering with all the elements in the set. in my case, the set contains a list of strings that I've used in the mongo query (nin block) to obtain just the elements that disappeared on the second date.  I hope that I was clear enough